# Adding a database to web.config & External Data Model edmx in MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am extending an existing project by adding a new process which will reside on an existing project's website (and use the same look/feel) but the new process does not interact with the existing processes.  In other words, I'm adding a new feature.

The database I'm going to create will reside on the same SQL instance as the existing project's database.  The existing connection string in the web.config has the initial catalog set to the existing project's database.  I will need to switch to the new database for the pieces of the project I'm going to create.  Do I need to add a new connection string to the web.config?  Or is there a way to reference the new catalog using the existing connection string?

Comment: add another connection string key/value and name it what ever you like and reference it the same way you would the working one..

Comment: ok, that was my initial thought, but I wasn't sure if that was a common way to handle this scenario.

Comment: yes you can add as many as you like and I am quite sure many developers use that technique and or you could store it in settings and then override it by referencing the config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a separate edmx.  To keep things organized, I placed it in a separate project folder in my solution, so the original edmx is in one folder, and the new edmx is in a separate folder.  I also have a separate app.config in each folder.  So, my new folder is structured in the same way as the original one.

New Folder for my data model additions to the original project:

[image]